# AS3 Trigger to Label using IF Statement

Tags: actionscript-3

I have problem to find the way to identify frame label inside child's timeline using **if** statement. I wrote the following but failed.

```
if (myChild.currentFrame == "b1"){
myMC.visible=false;
}
```

myMC is on parent timeline. Then nothing occurred. Please help

Comment: Because the **currentFrame** property returns the 1-based integer index of the current frame. You should use the **currentFrameLabel** property instead.

Comment: Yes, it work perfectly using **currentFrameLabel**. Thank so much